# Error in installing newspaper3k package via pip

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to install `newspaper3k`.
I am doing all accordingly to the [installation guide](http://newspaper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide/install.html#install)

`sudo apt-get install python-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev`

`pip3 install newspaper`

While running `pip install newspaper` I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_ovd/nltk/setup.py", line 23, in <module>

    distribute_setup.use_setuptools()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_ovd/nltk/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools

    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)

  File "/tmp/pip_build_ovd/nltk/distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download

    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)

  File "/tmp/pip_build_ovd/nltk/distribute_setup.py", line 116, in _build_egg

    raise IOError('Could not build the egg.')

OSError: Could not build the egg.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ovd/nltk
```

I have never faced with errors of this type. What is the way to fix it and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation from github have helped me.

`pip3 install git+https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper.git`

Answer (score 2):

Some clarification:

```
 pip3 install newspaper3k
```

and

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper.git
```

are both for Python 3.  If you want the Python 2.7 version you can use

```
pip install newspaper
```

However I kept getting the problem described by the OP.  The problem is that the Python 2.7 version explicitly lists the version numbers of the required libraries.  To fix this download the file from

https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/newspaper/newspaper-0.0.9.8.tar.gz#md5=331375b5a941e038a73827ea014d4c21

Unzip it into a folder.  Then open the requirements.txt file and change all the `==` to `>=`.  This will allow you to use the latest version of dependencies.  Optionally you can only change this for the dependencies you're having a problem with, but then pip will uninstall your current versions and install the older versions.  However, if newspaper ends up with errors with the new versions this might fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You're installing the wrong package. It's actually:

`pip3 install newspaper3k`

Answer (score 1):

I think that on pypi "newspaper" is the python2 branch. Try: `pip install newspaper3k`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Anaconda and the way that worked for me was

```
conda install -c conda-forge newspaper3k
```